# How to disable FireFox extensions through Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, firefox, scheduled-tasks, firefox-extensions, task-scheduler

I've set Task Scheduler to toggle various tasks depending on the time of day, such as setting Windows to dark mode at night and light mode at day. In keeping with this setup, I'd like to automatically disable Firefox's Dark Reader extension in the day and enable it at night.

Is there a way for Task Scheduler (or a similar automated method) to disable a specific Firefox extension, such as Dark Reader?

Answer (score 1):

I have traced the execution of Firefox when disabling or enabling
the extension Dark Reader in `about:addons`, and discovered that
the only effect of disabling or enabling is to modify the file
`extensions.json` inside the profile folder.

More specifically, the following bold text is toggeled between
`true` and `false` :

> {"id":"addon@darkreader.org","syncGUID":"{a0e1e725-bfcf-4bf6-bd72-9a0e2c9d766d}","version":"4.9.62","type":"extension","loader":null,"updateURL":null,"installOrigins":null,"manifestVersion":2,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"optionsBrowserStyle":true,"aboutURL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Dark Reader","description":"Dark mode for every website. Take care of your eyes, use dark theme for night and daily browsing.","creator":"Alexander Shutau","developers":null,"translators":null,"contributors":null},"visible":true,"active":true,**"userDisabled":false**,

Firefox need to be restarted for any modification of this file to take
effect, and the modification needs to be done when Firefox is closed.

Rather than suggesting to text-edit the file, a simpler solution would
be to keep two copies of the file : One when the extension is enabled
and the other is when it's disabled.

The two scheduled tasks would then just kill Firefox if it's running
using the command [taskkill](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)
as follows :

```
taskkill /im firefox.exe /f
```

Then copy the required version of `extensions.json` to the profile
folder. Restarting Firefox is not recommended in a scheduled task.

If killing Firefox is too violent, you would just need to restart
it manually some time after the scheduled task has run.

You would need to recreate the two versions of `extensions.json`
anytime that you would install, uninstall or in any way change the
state of any extension that is not Dark Reader.
If that is a problem, you could implement a different solution
that modifies in-place the file `extensions.json`.

Note : To find the profile folder in Firefox, go to
*Settings > Help > More troubleshooting information*,
field "Profile Folder".

Comment: I installed a new Firefox, and I can now open the folder! Thank you! Now, I found `extensions` as a JSON file, which I opened through Notepad. I then used Ctrl+F and searched `addon@darkreader.org","syncGUID":"` to find the relevant extension. From there, I located `"userDisabled":false` as you said in your instructions. I changed "false" to "true" to see if anything would happen, but the extension was still enabled. I even went to Task Manager and chose to "End task" for Firefox, but it's still enabled. (Because of this, I changed `userDisabled` back to "true.") What should I try next?

Comment: You shouldn't leave Firefox running while you're modifying `extensions.json` (and don't forget to save the file...)

Comment: So, I've tried testing it, but changing `userDisabled` to true didn't solve the problem. In fact, I restarted my computer, and the extension is still there. _However_, I noticed something: Although the app is working, if I go to "Add-ons and themes" (AKA "Add-ons Manager), the toggle button looks as if the extension is disabled, but it's listed within the "Enabled section." Thus, setting `userDisabled` to "true" did something, but it didn't go far enough. My guess is that I should make other settings "true" as well. If so, which ones?

Comment: In my testing `userDisabled` was enough to disable Dark Mode. I don't know why it doesn't behave the same for you, but you could try also setting `appDisabled` and `embedderDisabled`. However, it would be simpler to just let Firefox do the enable or disable in `about:addons` - save two copies of `extensions.json`, one enabled and one disabled and use them. Or compare them for differences, which is what I did using [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/).

Comment: That was a good idea. Now, I just manually disabled the extension and then copied the `extensions.json` file. In addition, I manually enabled the extension file and then saved the `extensions.json` file. When I've swapped them this time, it changes what's been toggled but, as before, the function is static. In your testing, does Dark Reader actually disappear/reappear, from the list of extensions at the top-right corner of the screen? And does Dark Reader stop working/resume working through each swap?

Comment: Yes, it's quite easy to see if Dark Reader is working or not. I really can't explain why it's not working for you. I don't use Firefox as my main browser and have no other add-ons than Dark Reader installed. I assume your setup is different than mine. Check if when you close Firefox there is not some `firefox.exe` that is still left running. Check perhaps if enabling/disabling Dark Reader changes other file(s) in the profile folder.

Comment: It's strange indeed. Looking around the folder, I found my Profile Folder has an "extensions" folder with `addon@darkreader.org.xpi` as a file. If I remove it, Dark Reader becomes uninstalled from Firefox. If I bring it back, it reinstalls, but Firefox makes me go to the addons page and accept it because "another program" installed the extension. Is there a way to make Firefox automatically accept extensions added through "another program"? If so, that would solve my problem completely by fully automating the process!

Comment: I don't know of a method for doing that, but your solution has an important flaw. If Firefox is running, a scheduled task will fail to delete the extension file as it's open by Firefox. You might manage to semi-delete it by instead renaming the file, so it will not be available when Firefox is re-launched.

Comment: While `addon@darkreader.org.xpi` can't be deleted, it can be moved. Doing so stops dark mode from appearing on new pages! Also, if I move the file back to the "extensions" folder when Firefox is still open, dark mode returns to new pages. All this is exactly what I'm looking for! The only problem is that if `addon@darkreader.org.xpi` is outside the "extensions" folder when Firefox starts, I'll have to accept Dark Reader next time I move it to "extensions," as it thinks "another program" installed it. How can I schedule a task to move files? (I'll ask about auto-accepting extensions elsewhere.)

Comment: I would always keep an emergency copy of the XPI in case the task scheduling got mixed up. Its very easy to create a scheduled task(s) that will execute batch script(s), which will do the moving. There is lots of information to be found about the Task Scheduler. If you're looking for information, see [an example](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).

Comment: I've gotten too bogged down in trying to get this to work. As a result, I just switched to Midnight Lizard, as it seems to serve my purposes. Although you weren't able to solve my problem, you worked really hard to help, so enjoy the bounty!

Comment: Thank you. It was an interesting subject that we explored together.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a script do so, and employ Task Scheduler to run it during the time you desire it to run. Follow along:

First, open any text editor such as Notepad and copy-paste the following code:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"
start firefox.exe -no-remote -CreateProfile "tempProfile"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
start firefox.exe -P tempProfile -no-remote "about:config"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -P tempProfile -CreateProfile "tempProfile" "about:config#extensions.{EXTENSION_ID}.enabled"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
taskkill /f /im firefox.exe
```

- Save the file with a `.bat` extension.
- Open Windows Task Scheduler.
- Click "Create Task" in the Actions panel.
- Fill in "General" tab with some Name. Description is optional.
- In "Triggers" tab, set the schedule for the task.
- In the "Actions" tab, click "New" and set the "Action" to "Start a program".
- In the "Program/Script" input field, browse to the location of your file with `.bat` extension to select it.
- Click "OK" and save the task.

*Please note that you need to replace the `{EXTENSION_ID}` in the above code with the extension ID which you can find out in add-ons manager. The id is in the URL of the page for that specific extension.
If the extension ID is `asuperuserquestion@superuser` the line should be:*

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -P tempProfile -CreateProfile "tempProfile" "about:config#extensions.asuperuserquestion@superuser.enabled"
```

I hope this solves the problem :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will upvote if I can have more help with this. I learned online that I can find the extension ID by going to `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox`. For Dark Reader, the Extension ID is `addon@darkreader.org`, the Internal UUID is `ab00ea21-616d-464c-bb4b-810509b501af`, and the Manifest URL is `moz-extension://ab00ea21-616d-464c-bb4b-810509b501af/manifest.json`. I tried running my .bat file by trying each of these IDs/URLs in place of `{EXTENSION_ID}`. However, I was told, "The system cannot find the path specified." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's an example of code that failed to work: `@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"
start firefox.exe -no-remote -CreateProfile "tempProfile"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
start firefox.exe -P tempProfile -no-remote "about:config"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -P tempProfile -CreateProfile "tempProfile" "about:config#extensions.addon@darkreader.org.enabled"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
taskkill /f /im firefox.exe`.

Comment: Aha! Checking my Application Binary at `about:support`, I found Firefox in the folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Mozilla.Firefox_109.0.1.0_x64__n80bbvh6b1yt2\VFS\ProgramFiles\Firefox Package Root`. Therefore, I switched to this code. Instead of being told, "The system cannot find the path specified," I was now told, "Access is denied." So, I went [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-windows-apps-hidden-folder-and-why-cant-i/40a60508-c409-422a-af92-bd51fe5a4ca9) to gain permission. Afterward, Firefox stopped working in its folder (error 0xc0000022). What now?

Comment: The "Access is denied" error message often indicates that the user executing the script lacks the rights required to run the file.

Try executing the script in administrative mode. Right-click the .bat file and choose "Run as administrator" to do this. You ought to be able to disable the Firefox extension if the script executes correctly.

Even if you execute the script as an administrator, you can still get the "Access is denied" error if the firefox.exe file's rights have been limited. Try modifying the file's permissions to provide the user account running the script complete control.

Comment: I've done some testing to get it to work and discovered there is more than one path leading to firefox.exe. Of course, there's `:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Mozilla.Firefox_109.0.1.0_x64__n80bbvh6b1yt2\VFS\ProgramFiles\Firefox Package Root`, but I also discovered that I have another path at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\firefox.exe` (where [username] is the administrator username). When I run this path, however, the extension still isn't removed. To make sure it's something on my end, could I ask you to install Dark Reader to see if your script works on your end?

Comment: No matter what I've tried, the current answer seems incomplete, as I'm unable to remove the extension. Do the instructions you provided let you 1) automatically disable Dark Reader at a certain time (e.g., 7 AM or whenever your computer turns on) and 2) automatically enable Dark Reader at night (e.g., 7 PM)? For reference, the extension can be found [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/darkreader/), and its Extension ID is `addon@darkreader.org`. Something seems incomplete with your answer, so let me know if you can automatically disable/enable Dark Reader. Thanks! :)